# How can I formulate these constraints for the optimization math programming (MIP)

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I am struggling with some constraints that have ranged variables and several decision variables.

The constraints are

```
`if a[i] <= t <= a[i]+b[i], then M[t][i] == 1,
else if t < a[i] or t > a[i]+b[i], then M[t][i] == 0.


decision variables (int a[i], b[i])
                    (boolean M[t][i])
Examples of ranges of the variables 
0 <= a[i] <= 50
0 <= b[i] <= 10
0 <= t <= 100`
```

I'd like to linearize these formulations, like as Big-M method or etc...

Plz, let me know the way to overcome it.
Thank you.

Linearization by using the Big-M method or etc...

such as...

```
M*t + (M-1)*t <= M*(a[i]) + (M-1)*a[i]
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://or.stackexchange.com/